# Installing Numpy with python 2.7.13 for windows 7 32-bit

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to install open cv for a while , according TO INSTRUCTIONS the numpy library should be automatically installed with 2.7.13 but when i try to import it it gives the following error:
Numpy.core.multiarray Failed to import

Comment: For windows I'd really recommend installing python through the Anaconda distribution. Numpy comes preinstalled and OpenCV is few commands from there.

Comment: Did that , now it says when import cv2 that this version may conflict
I'm using open cv3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

It also came across the same problem. I installed "numpy" manually in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. You can find the latest versions of numpy [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/). You can download the executable file directly. Just install it at the location I previously mentioned. Hope this is helpful.